# Unable to limit browser session to 1 using maxSession in Selenium grid (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-grid

I am using below command to start Node and I could see that more than one browser instances are launched parallely when thread-count is more than 1 in testNG suite. Please note that I am not using Firefox browser installed in the machine, instead I am using copying the firefox binaries and using the same for my testing. Also, once the test starts runnning I could see configuration has "maxSessions=1",but still multiple tests are running in parallel instances of browser.

```
java -jar ${jarLocation} -role webdriver -hub ${hubRegisterURL} -port ${port} -log ${gridNodeLog} -maxSession 1
```

Please help....!

Comment: Shouldn't Hub be configured with `"maxSessions=n"` as well? Update the question with the commands you have used to start Hub/Node for further analysis

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
-browser browserName=firefox,maxSession=1,maxInstances=1,platform=LINUX
```

You can start grid nodes that are configured with a JSON configuration file

```
$ java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -role node -nodeConfig node1Config.json
```

And here is an example of a nodeConfig.json file:

```
{
  "capabilities": [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "acceptSslCerts": true,
      "javascriptEnabled": true,
      "takesScreenshot": false,
      "firefox_profile": "",
      "browser-version": "27",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "firefox_binary": "",
      "cleanSession": true 
    }
  ],
    "configuration": {
        "_comment" : "Configuration for Node",
        "cleanUpCycle": 2000,
        "timeout": 30000,
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.WebDriverRemoteProxy",
        "port": 5555,
        "host": ip,
        "register": true,
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "maxSessions": 1
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried -browser browserName=firefox,maxSession=1,maxInstances=1,platform=LINUX, but it does not work.. Also, I can not add nodeConfig.json file.  If we see the configuration setting after the Node is started it clearly shows maxSession is set to 1, but I could see multiple browsers running parallely.

Comment: Also, can we synchronize the access to grid node by changing some parameters in node start command so that only 1 thread can access a grid node at a time.